# What is the use of org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, aem

I have been using Adobe CQ5 . There in the web.xml file , I noticed a servlet named `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` .

I want to know the use of this `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` in terms of CQ5 and in general.

I saw http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet.html
. But , not able to understand its functionality . What is the added advantage this class is giving on top of HttpServlet ?

What is the need of calling this servlet in the context of Adobe CQ5 ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I have no idea what CQ5 is, but in a normal JSP/Servlet web application, the `JspServlet` is normally configured in servletcontainer's own `web.xml` and this servlet will enable using JSP files in the webapp. It's exactly that servlet which get executed when a `*.jsp` URL has been requested and this servlet will take care about all the JSP works "behind the scenes". So, without that servlet, you won't be able to use JSP files. So, if you don't need JSP files at all, you can safely remove it from the `web.xml`. Perhaps *you* can now understand it better in context of CQ5.

Comment: Hi Balus, CQ5 is an Adobe CMS based on Apache Sling/ExtJS, (which uses JSPs within the View layer of it's templating system).

Comment: BalusC : Its clear to me . I have one question then . When we create a java based web app , even if we dont provide org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet in web.xml , the java app works fine and accepts jsp files. What goes on in that case ?

Comment: As said, the `JspServlet` is by default already definied in the servletcontainer's own `web.xml`.